# Can I make Entity Framework use sqlite's LIKE instead of instr()?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core, sql-like, case-insensitive

Currently using .NET Core 2.

I use a LINQ query similar to:

```
var peopleInRoseStreet = context.Person
    .Include(p => p.Addresses)
    .Where(p => p.Addresses.Any(a => a.Text.Contains("rose")));
```

EF seems to translate this to:

```
SELECT "p".*
FROM "Person" AS "p"
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM "PersonAddress" AS "a"
    WHERE (instr("a"."Text", 'rose') > 0) AND ("p"."Id" = "a"."person_id"))
ORDER BY "p"."Id"
```

By using `instr()`, the comparison is case-sensitive although the PersonAddress.Text column is set to `COLLATE NOCASE`. If I modify the query above to use `LIKE` instead, the search is case-insensitive as I intend it.

Is it possible to force EF to use `LIKE`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`EF.Functions.Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/) introduced in EF Core 2.0:

```
var peopleInRoseStreet = context.Person
    .Include(p => p.Addresses)
    .Where(p => p.Addresses.Any(a => EF.Functions.Like(a.Text, "%rose%")));
```